# Query to Convert a specific 12 hour format type to 24 hour format type in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, date-formatting, sql-server-2016-express

We have a case where the time edited by users is in the format `3/2/20 3:30P` (where P denotes P.m.) which I'm trying to convert to the 24hour format to be able to use a join condition with a standard column to something like `2020-03-02 15:30:0000`

e.g. `3/2/20 3:30P` to `2020-03-02 15:30:0000`

Tried the below ways in one of the answers in StackOverflow, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM', 0)  
-- Concatenate in required format
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM', 0), 101) 
+ ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/1/2013 6:39:04  PM', 0), 108)
```

Comment: What format is your data actually in? In the text of your question you say it's `M/d/yy h:mm{P/A}`, but in the SQL example you have (what I assume) is `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss  {PM/AM}`. Which is it? Those are 2 completely different formats.

Comment: SELECT Cast('3/2/20 3:30P' +'M' AS datetime) would do it. You can do the same with convert, using the default style 0.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - you're right as well, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** that the format is `M/d/yy h:mmA (or P)` then I would use the style code `22`, which is for `mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ss AM (or PM)`, so that this works regardless of language setting:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),V.YourDate + 'M',22)
FROM (VALUES('3/2/20 3:30P'))V(YourDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
DECLARE @dates VARCHAR(255) = '3/2/20 3:30P'

SELECT @dates AS Old_Date, 
       CONVERT(DATETIME, @dates + RIGHT(RIGHT(@dates, 1) + 'm', 1)) AS New_Date
```